# Growing trees from seed & cuttings

Tags: trees, propagation, cuttings, resources

I would like to learn and compare the different methods to grow trees from seeds. I found a good website (http://treegrowing.tcv.org.uk/grow), and one [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Growing-Trees-Seed-Practical-Shrubs/dp/1554073634/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1426081937&sr=8-1&keywords=grow%20trees%20from%20seed), but the latter seems to be good for American species mainly (I live in UK).

Could anyone suggest some references?
I am also very interested in learning and compare the different species of trees and shrubs that can be propagated from cuttings.

A detailed guide on the propagation of trees and shrubs, in general, with all the different ways (water propagation, air layering, from seed with stratification, etc.) would be perfect.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't beat RHS (Royal Horticultural Society) publications if you're in the UK - there's one called RHS Propagating Plants by Alan Toogood (available on Amazon), also RHS Handbook: Propagation Techniques, again available at Amazon, also available as a Kindle download.

Answer (score 4):

I enjoyed Secrets of Plant Propagation: Starting Your Own Flowers, Vegetables, Fruits, Berries, Shrubs, Trees, and Houseplants by Lewis Hill. It is packed pretty densely with images of different propagation tactics for all sorts of plants. May be lacking in some of the more modern techniques but still a great resource that's easy to understand.